# Dedekind eta function at cusp other than infinity

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, dedekind-eta-function

(Sorry for my poor english...)

Let $\triangle(z)=q\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^n)^{24}$ be a cusp form of weight $12$.   Let $N$ be a positive integer, $\delta \mid N$ and $\triangle_{\delta}(z)=\triangle(\delta z)$. Let $s=\frac{b}{d}$ be a cusp on $\Gamma_0(N)$ with $(b,d)=1$ and $\rho\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with $\rho(s)=i\infty$.

Lemma 3.2.5 in Ligozat's paper ("Courbes modulaires de genre 1) says that
\begin{equation}
\triangle_{\delta}(\rho^{-1}(z))=\left(\frac{d}{\delta}(d,\delta)z+\beta\right)^{12}\triangle\left(\frac{(d,\delta)^2}{\delta}z+\gamma \right)
\end{equation}
with some integers $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

In the proof of this lemma, let $\rho=\begin{pmatrix} c & -a\\
d & -b \end{pmatrix}. $ Then,
\begin{equation}
\triangle_{\delta}(\rho^{-1}(z))=\triangle\left(\begin{pmatrix} -b\delta & a\\
-d & c \end{pmatrix}z\right).
\end{equation} 
I think that 
\begin{equation}
\triangle_{\delta}(\rho^{-1}(z))=\triangle\left(\begin{pmatrix} -b\delta & a\delta\\
-d & c \end{pmatrix}z\right).
\end{equation}
What's wrong in my idea..?

Furthermore, I want to show Lemma 3.2.5 myself as follow.. 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\triangle_{\delta}(\rho^{-1}(z))&=\triangle_{\delta}\left(\frac{-cz+a}{-dz+b} \right)\\
&=\triangle\left(\frac{-c\delta'(d,\delta)z+a\delta}{-d'(d,\delta)z+b} \right)\\
&=\triangle\left(\frac{-c\delta'u+a\delta}{-d'u+b} \right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with $\frac{d}{d'}=\frac{\delta}{\delta'}=(d,\delta)$ and $u=(d,\delta)z$.
Then, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
-c\delta'& a\delta\\
-d' & b
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 
-c\delta' & \alpha\\
d' & \beta
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \gamma \\
0 & \delta'
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation} 
with $\begin{pmatrix} 
-c\delta' & \alpha\\
d' & \beta
\end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ are integers. Since $\triangle(z)$ is a cusp form, 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\triangle\left(\frac{-c\delta'u+a\delta}{-d'u+b} \right)&=\triangle\left(\frac{-c\delta'(\frac{u+\gamma}{\delta'})+\alpha}{-d'(\frac{u+\gamma}{\delta'})+\beta} \right)\\
&=\left(-d'\left(\frac{u+\gamma}{\delta'}\right)+\beta \right)^{12}\triangle\left(\frac{u+\gamma}{\delta'} \right)\\
&=\left(-\frac{d}{\delta}(d,\delta)z+\frac{b}{\delta'} \right)^{12}\triangle\left(\frac{(d,\delta)^2}{\delta}z+\frac{\gamma}{\delta'} \right).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
However, $\frac{b}{\delta'}$ and $\frac{\gamma}{\delta'}$ are not integers..

Where is my mistake...?